# ovs-vsctl: "eth0" is not a valid UUID

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization

I'm trying to setup an open v-switch inside my Ubuntu 12.04 Server VM. I have created three interfaces for this VM and I want to create a port mirror inside of the VM using these there interfaces and open v-switch.

There are three Host-Only Adapters: eth0, eth1, eth2. The idea is that three other VM's will be connected to these adapters. One of these VM's will stream UDP video to eth0 and I want the vswitch'd VM to mirror those packets from eth0 onto eth1 and eth2. Each of the VM's connected to eth1 and eth2 will get the same video stream.

I performed the following steps to install open v-switch:

```
$ apt-get install python-simplejson python-qt4 python-twisted-conch automake autoconf gcc uml-utilities libtool build-essential
$ apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake pkg-config
$ wget http://openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-1.7.1.tar.gz
$ tar xf http://openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-1.7.1.tar.gz
$ cd http://openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-1.7.1.tar.gz
$ apt-get install libssl-dev iproute tcpdump linux-headers-`uname -r`
$ ./boot.sh
$ ./configure - -with-linux=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After installation I configured as follows:

```
$ insmod datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko
$ sudo touch /usr/local/etc/ovs-vswitchd.conf
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/openvswitch
$ ovsdb-tool create /usr/local/etc/openvswitch/conf.db
```

Then I started the server:

```
$ ovsdb-server /usr/local/etc/openvswitch/conf.db \
  --remote=punix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock \
  --remote=db:Open_vSwitch,manager_options \
  --private-key=db:SSL,private_key \
  --certificate=db:SSL,certificate \
  --bootstrap-ca-cert=db:SSL,ca_cert --pidfile --detach --log-file
$ ovs-vsctl –no-wait init (run only once)
$ ovs-vswitchd --pidfile --detach
```

The above steps I got from [this](http://networkstatic.net/installing-and-configuring-openvswitch-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) tutorial and it all worked fine. I then proceeded to add a port mirror based on the open v-switch documentation under [Port Mirroring](http://openvswitch.org/cgi-bin/ovsman.cgi?page=utilities/ovs-vsctl.8#EXAMPLES). I successfully completed the following commands:

```
$ ovs-vsctl add-br br0
$ ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
$ ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth1
$ ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth2
$ ifconfig eth0 promisc up
$ ifconfig eth1 promisc up
$ ifconfig eth2 promisc up
```

At this point when I run ovs-vsctl show I get the following:

```
75bda8c2-b870-438b-9115-e36288ea1cd8
    Bridge "br0"
        Port "br0"
            Interface "br0"
                type: internal
        Port "eth0"
            Interface "eth0"
        Port "eth2"
            Interface "eth2"
        Port "eth1"
            Interface "eth1"
```

And when I run ifconfig I get the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9f:51:ca  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe9f:51ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1494 (1.4 KB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:53:02:d4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe53:2d4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1494 (1.4 KB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:cb:a5:93  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fecb:a593/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1494 (1.4 KB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:df:bb:d8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.139  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fedf:bbd8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2211 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:182987 (182.9 KB)  TX bytes:125441 (125.4 KB)
```

NOTE: I use eth3 as a bridge adapter for SSH'ing into the VM.

So now, I think I've done everything correctly but when I try to create the bridge using the following command:

```
$ ovs-vsctl -- set Bridge br0 mirrors=@m -- --id=@eth0 get Port eth0 -- --id=@eth1 get Port eth1 -- --id=@m create Mirror name=app1Mirror select-dst-port=eth0 select-src-port=@eth0 output-port=@eth1,@eth2
```

I get the following error:

```
ovs-vsctl: "eth0" is not a valid UUID
```

I don't understand why it's not able to find the interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some searching turns out I made two mistakes:

- missing @ infront of eth0: select-dst-port=eth0 should be select-dst-port=@eth0
- You can only add a rule one at a time for each output port. So at the end you can only say output-port=@eth1 and not output-port=@eth1,@eth2